# Python serial ports

Tags: python, serial-port, raspberry-pi, ports

I need to run both zigbee and SMS dongle on a raspberry pi, that means having to run both ports in a python script. Since xbee is always on ttyUSB0, is there a way I could set the dongle on ttyUSB1 or ttyUSB2 so that i dont have to configure it via gammu command everytime it is plugged in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing to do here is use a udev rule. This will allow you to symlink the device to a specific port, something like /dev/ttyXBEE and /dev/ttySMS in your case.

To accomplish this, you need to query the devices using `udevadm` to find some unique identifying information, then create a file `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-usbserial.rules` that will tell the Pi how to map the device.

[This thread has an example.](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=90265)